# I am struggling with types in appending data to IOS contacts code below gives an error

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact

I am trying to amend a contact in my IOS app but get type error 
 Value of type '[CNContact]' has no member 'familyName'

```
    let updateContact = try contactStore.unifiedContacts(matching: predicate,keysToFetch: toFetch as [CNKeyDescriptor])
            updateContact.familyName.append(CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelWork, value: contact["2"]!))
```

Clearly i have the wrong type for updateContact but can't figure where I have gone wrong

Comment: may be your current contact dont have family name

Answer (score 2):

The properties that you want to fetch for the `CNContacts` objects returned by the call to `unifiedContacts` is specified in the `toFetch` array. Did you specify the familyName value as part of the `toFetch` array?

If you are not sure, please provide the code that you used to set up the `toFetch` array.

**Update:**
The call to `unifiedContacts` returns an array of `CNContact` objects. That's why you were getting an error. You'd have to get a `CNContact` instance out of the array and then modify it. Something like this:

```
if let updateContact = try contactStore.unifiedContacts(matching: predicate,keysToFetch: toFetch as [CNKeyDescriptor]).first {
    let name = updateContact.familyName + contact["2"]!
    updateContact.setValue(name, forKey:CNContactFamilyNameKey)
}
```

Comment: let predicate = CNContact.predicateForContacts(matchingName: delCont)
 

  let toFetch =   [CNContactGivenNameKey] + [CNContactFamilyNameKey]

Comment: @Jeremy If you can provide the full project, I can debug this easier to see what is going on :)

Comment: OK, I missed this the first time around - the call to `unifiedContacts` returns an array of `CNContact` objects. That's why you were getting an error. You'd have to get a `CNContact` instance out of the array and then modify it.

Comment: +1 The answer is in the update: `unifiedContacts` returns an array of contacts (obvious really when you think about it)

Comment: Could you please mark it as "correct" if the code I provided works for you?

Comment: Fahim  My problem still is how to update other elements like organisation  phone numbers, email - i.e. overwriting existing values rather than adding a new record\

Comment: @Jeremy Did you see my code above where the Family Name value is updated? That's how you'd set values for other properties on a CNContact object as well. Basically, the following - `updateContact.setValue(name, forKey:CNContactFamilyNameKey)`

Comment: Thanks once again - I did see the code and it works fine for names but my issue is understanding the update of the items like email phone number i.e. the ones with multiple values.
Weill leave it for awhile and then have another try

Comment: @Jeremy Phone numbers, URLs, e-mail addresses etc. come as arrays for the `CNContact` object. So, if you know the value you want to replace, you'd have to loop through the array, find the object with the value you want, and then set the new value for that object. If you don't know the exact value but have a new list of values, you'd simply replace the old list with the new list or create a combined list of both sets of values - depends on what you want.